# How can I target a specific element on scroll in React using JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to target my About section on scroll, to add a class to the about section to make it fade in on scroll. As well as other sections as well I would like to target on scroll. Is there a way to target the specific element by ID or something on scroll?

```
showAbout = () => {
  const top = window.pageYOffset;
  if(top>400)
  this.setState({
  showAbout: true,
  })
}

componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.showAbout)
}
```

This is the code I have currently, 400 is more of an arbitrary number, its different on each screen size. I was wondering if there is a way to do this same function, but by targeting the element ID on scroll?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you looked into the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) API? It's essentially purpose-built to allow for transitions when elements scroll into view on the page. If you are looking to fade the about section in when it comes into view, using this will save you from having to use pre-set Y-offsets.

Comment: are you looking for `document.getElementById()` ?

Comment: I'd suggest using https://github.com/dbramwell/react-animate-on-scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the exact window offset for each of these elements on page load and trigger your animation when those offsets hit. You would also need to have a window.resize event that re-calculates those offsets for when a user resizes their window (or changes orientation on a phone).

OR, you can use a pre-built JS library to do this a lot easier for you. My recommendation is Scroll Magic:
https://scrollmagic.io/

You can indeed set up trigger points based on element IDs, and it works very smoothly.

Comment: Thanks! If i'm using this on a portfolio, would employers count it against me to use a pre-built library?

Comment: I would hope not... JS devs use libraries like jQuery, etc in real life all the time. I'm not sure why an employee would be angry about you using a library that makes the math easier. I would make sure you know what it's doing though, i.e. dynamically calculating the offset position for an element passed to it, and triggering events based on the scroll position with calculations for how far you're into the event area, etc.